# физический движок Unity, 2D, Деформация объектов

Tags: unity3d

Почему физика в Unity так деформирует шестиугольники? Из-за чего такое происходит?
Это, конечно, фича, а не баг, но никак не могу понять как этого избежать.

[image: введите сюда описание изображения]

Comment: А Вы уверены, что это деформация, а не поворот по какой-нибудь из осей?

Comment: Возникало такое подозрение, но нет.

Comment: Что вы имеете ввиду под "так деформирует шестиугольники"? У вас какой-то код их деформирует? Вы вручную?

Comment: @ArtikSlayer, Сначала это обычные правильные шестиугольники, потом они падают под действием гравитации и появляются вот такие сжатия и подобные деформации.